# Cancellation of a sum of a product of analytic functions

Tags: polynomials, analytic-functions

Consider a (finite, $k = 1, \ldots, K < \infty$) collection of analytic functions $p_k(z)$ and $q_k(z)$, where $p_k(0) = 0$ and $q_k(0) = 0$.

Suppose also that all of $p_k$ and $q_k$ have an infinite number of nonzero terms.  That is to say

$$
  p_k(z) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty p_n^{(k)}z^n,
$$

where $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n > N$ s.t. $p_n^{(k)} \ne 0$.

Then define

\begin{align}
T(z) &= \sum_{k = 1}^K p_k(z)q_k(1/z)\\
&= \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty t_n z^n.
\end{align}

Is it possible that $\exists n > 0$ such that $t_n \ne 0$ but $\forall n < 0$ we have $t_n = 0$?  i.e. that $T(z)$ is one-sided?

It seems that it could only be possible that $T(z) = 0$ (i.e. if $p_1 = p_2$ and $q_1 = -q_2$), but that $T(z)$ can't be one-sided.

I'm not very well versed in this kind of function theory, but it seems there should be some theorems that can help to understand this situation.

Comment: How about $p_1(z)=z^2$, $q_1(w)=w$?

Comment: I'm looking specifically for a case where each $p$ and $q$ have an infinite number of non-zero terms.  i.e. that they are not just polynomials.  My intuition is that in this case there are "too many things that need to cancel".

Answer (score 1):

I have synthesized the ideas of other posters into a definitively positive answer with $K = 2$.

Take $h(z) = \sum_{n = 2}^\infty h_n z^{n}$, with each $h_n \ne 0$.  Then,

$p_1(z) = z^2 + h(z), p_2(z) = p_1(z)$

$q_1(z) = z + h(z), q_2(z) = z - h(z).$

This works out to

$p_1(z)q_1(1/z) + p_2(z)q_2(1/z) = 2z + 2z^{-1}h(z)$, which is one sided.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I misunderstand, but I think modifying the idea of Mindlack for infinitely many nonzero terms, what about  $p_k(z) = 2^{-k}z^2$ and $q_k(w)=2^{-k}w$. Then we have $$T(z)=\sum_{k \geq 0}4^{-k}z =z \sum_{k \geq 0} 4^{-k} = \frac{4}{3}z$$ which has a one-sided Laurent series.

Comment: I think I my formulation of the question might be kind of confusing.  I mean that there are an infinite number of powers of $z$, that $p$ and $q$ are not just run of the mill polynomials.  I made an edit to the question to try to be more precise.

Comment: Let $h(z)$ be any "polynomial" with infinitely many terms. For even $k = 2s$, define $p_k = 2^{-k} z^2 + 2^{-s} h(z)$; for odd $k = 2s - 1$, define $p_k(z) = 2^{-k}z^2 - 2^{-s}h(z)$, so that the $h$ parts of successive odd-even pairs cancel when they are summed. Then each of these $p_k$ has infinitely many nonzero terms, but the sum of the $p_k$ is exactly the one that @Cade gives; you can do the same thing for the $q_k$. So Cade's answer, every-so-slightly modified, seems to give a negative answer to your question.